# How to write date in Italian and set italian as default language in ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, closedxml

I use `ClosedXML` to generate Excel file, taking data from Microsoft SQL Server. And I write the Date in this fotmat: `DDDD D-MM-yyyy`.The problem is that it writes in English. I want to set Italian language as default.

This is how I generate Excel file:

```
 foreach (Attivita attivita in listAttivita)
    {
        worksheet.Cell(index, 1).Value = attivita .Data;
        worksheet.Cell(index, 1).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "DDDD D-MM-yyyy";
        worksheet.Cell(index, 2).Value = attivita.Ord;
        worksheet.Cell(index, 3).Value = attivita.Straord;
        worksheet.Cell(index, 4).Value = attivita.Per;
        worksheet.Cell(index, 5).Value = attivita.Fer;
        worksheet.Cell(index, 6).Value = attivita.Mala;
        worksheet.Cell(index, 7).Value = attivita.Infor;
        worksheet.Cell(index, 8).Value = attivita.Cassa;
        index++;
      }
```

Allso I set `CultureInfo` in `Stratup.cs` but I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            
            CultureInfo[] supportedCultures = new[]
            {
                new CultureInfo("it-IT")
                //new CultureInfo("en")
            };

            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("it-IT");
                options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
                options.RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>
                {
                    new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider(),
                    new CookieRequestCultureProvider()
                };
            });
         }
```

Anycase this doesn't worked for me when I published the project in IIS.

---

**Update**

```
dddd d-mm-yyyy = "Thursday 28-August-2014"
```

[image]

---

**Update 2:**

Value of `attivita.Data` :

```
attivita.Data = {01/12/2020 00:00:00}
```

When I do this :

```
worksheet.Cell(index, 1).Value = attivita.Data.ToString("dddd, d-MMMM-yyyy", new CultureInfo("it-IT"));
```

The result is this :
[image]

---

And when I do this :

```
   worksheet.Cell(index, 1).Value = attivita.Data.ToString("dddd, d-mmmm-yyyy", new CultureInfo("it-IT"));
```

The result is this :
[image]

It should be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2WSt.png) . The only problem are the 00 that put there. And I can't get why is not working with this `dddd, d-MMMM-yyyy` that seems to be correct.

Any suggestions how to write the Date in italian, and set Italian as default language ?

Comment: `Attivita.Data` is DateTime?

Comment: Yes, it is DateTime

Comment: Maybe set the style before the value.

Comment: And try set 'DateFormat` in place `NumberFormat`.

Comment: No, it shoud be in this format `DDDD D-MM-yyyy`

Comment: I think that's the default behavior, if the format string has an error. Are you sure it's a valid format for Excel? Have you tried with small "d" and small "m"? In Excel, Month/Minute is context sensitive. That means "hh:mm" will display minutes, "yyyy/mm" will display month.

Comment: Yes I tried this: `dddd d-mm-yyyy` but nothing changed

Comment: What is the type of `Style`? Do it has other properties than `NumberFormat`?

Comment: @Vernou I just update my question.

Comment: This worked: `worksheet.Cell(index, 1).Value = data1.ToString("dddd, dd mmmm, yyyy", new CultureInfo("it-IT"));` but the result is : **martedì, 01 00, 2020** . Instead of 00 it should be Month. I can't get why it put 00 instead od Month

Comment: To display month's name, it's `MMMM` (uppercase).

Comment: The result with : `"dddd, d-MMMM-yyyy"`  --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0fB0.png   And the result with : `"dddd, d-mmmm-yyyy"` ---> https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2WSt.png

Answer (score 0):

When you set a DateTime in a cell, Excel display according to user's culture (generally Windows settings). You can convert in C# the DateTime to text to force format in Excel.

Example :

```cs
var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
var ws = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Data Types");

var co = 2;
var ro = 1;

ws.Cell(++ro, co).Value = "Plain Text:";
ws.Cell(ro, co + 1).Value = "Hello World.";

ws.Cell(++ro, co).Value = "Plain Date:";
ws.Cell(ro, co + 1).Value = new DateTime(2010, 9, 2);

ws.Cell(++ro, co).Value = "Plain Date as text in IT:";
ws.Cell(ro, co + 1).Value = new DateTime(2010, 9, 2).ToString(new CultureInfo("it-IT"));

ws.Cell(++ro, co).Value = "Plain Date as text in IT with custom format:";
ws.Cell(ro, co + 1).Value = new DateTime(2010, 9, 2).ToString("dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy", new CultureInfo("it-IT"));

// Resize columns 
ws.Columns(2, 3).AdjustToContents();

workbook.SaveAs("Test.xlsx");
```